# Simulation tree command in C

Tags: c, linux, tree, command, simulation

I have to create the simulation of tree command in C, this is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>


main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int i;

if(argc < 2){
    printf("\nError. Use: %s directory\n", argv[0]);
    system("exit");
}
for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
    //if(argv[i][0] != '-')
        tree(argv[i]);
}

tree(char *ruta){

DIR *dirp;
struct dirent *dp;
static nivel = 0;
struct stat buf;
char fichero[256];
int i;

if((dirp = opendir(path)) == NULL){
    perror(path);
    return;
}

while((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL){
    printf(fichero, "%s/%s", path, dp->d_name);
    if((buf.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR){
        for(i=0;i<nivel;i++)
            printf("\t");
        printf("%s\n", dp->d_name);
        ++nivel;
        tree(fichero);
        --nivel;
    }

}
}
```

Apparently, it works! (due to it compiles correctly) But I don't why. I can't pass the correct arguments to execute this.
Thank you so much, people.

Comment: For a start, `printf(fichero, "%s/%s", path, dp->d_name);` should probably read `snprintf(fichero, 256, "%s/%s", path, dp->d_name);`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. But it doesn't work yet. I think the problem is in the pass of arguments. It doesn't take the path that I give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must define `tree` before you use it or declare a prototype.
2. `tree` and `main` need return types.
3. `path` is not defined and `ruta` is used. Presumably these should be the same thing.
4. You never call `stat` to fill `buf` with the file you got in `dp` from `readdir`.

Special bonus: `nivel` is a bad idea. It would make better sense to have it as a parameter and have the root level pass in 0 and then, in each call to the child, pass `nivel+1`.

Also, “it compiles” says nothing about “it works”, especially in C.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where "path" is defined but you are not using the "ruta" pointer anywhere. I believe you should do some processing on "ruta" to convert it into a path or use "ruta" instead of "path".